# How to write apex code for below scenario

Tags: apex, trigger

Custom object 'Item' has 2 fields - 'Quantity' and look to account 'Account__c'.

Account object has a lookup field for Item, 'Item__c'. This field is set with a related item having higher quantity value.

Write a trigger to update the Item__c in account object, when a new Item__c is inserted and has higher quantity value.

I have the below code, and it works as expected. But I want to know if this needs any modifications in terms of industry standards and better perfoemances.

```
public static void handler2(List<Product_Test__c> newProds){
        Set<Id> accId = new Set<Id>();
        for(Product_Test__c p : newProds){
            accId.add(p.Account__c);
        }
        List<Account> accountList = [Select Id,Product_Test__c,Product_Test__r.Quantity__c from Account where Id in :accId];
        Map<Id,Account> mapAcc = new Map<Id,Account>();
        Map<Id,Decimal> mapAccQuant = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
        for(Account a : accountList){
            mapAccQuant.put(a.Id,a.Product_Test__r.Quantity__c);
            mapAcc.put(a.Id,a);
        }
        
        List<Account> accUp = new List<Account>();
        for(Product_Test__c p : newProds){
            if(p.Quantity__c > mapAccQuant.get(p.Account__c)){
                mapAcc.get(p.Account__c).Product_Test__c = p.Id;
                accUp.add(mapAcc.get(p.Account__c));
            }
        }
        update accUp;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Have you checked the Apex tutorials on Salesforce Trailhead and other websites?

Comment: You need to show some effort from your end and ask of you are stuck somewhere. This is not code providing service community.

Comment: I've downvoted this because it is a "do my work for me" question. This site is not a place to get your work done for free. I will consider retracting my downvote if you [edit] your question to show an honest attempt and point out a specific part of it that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Hi All, apologies. Wasting your time or making someone else do my work was not at all my intention. I have edited my question now. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCheng Modified my comments

Comment: @DerekF Modified my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the current code: if you insert multiple products for the same account and if at least two of them have a quantity greater than the one linked to the account, you'll add the same account multiple times in the `accUp` list therefore the update will throw an exception.
Moreover if it's the first time you add a Product for a new Account `a.Product_Test__r.Quantity__c` is null, so it will not enter into the if block `p.Quantity__c > mapAccQuant.get(p.Account__c)` because `Quantity > null` evaluates to false. You could check it from developer console:

```java
Decimal d1 = null;
Decimal d2 = 8;
String result = d2 > d1 ? 'Greater then null' : 'Else';
System.debug(result); // You'll see Else
```

For this task you need only one map, one list and two loops.
In the first loop over `newProds` you could store the product with the highest quantity for each account in a `Map<Id, Product_Test__c> mapAccoutIdToProduct`.
Now you have to:

- declare a list to store the accounts that need to be update
- looping over a query on Account filtered by the map's `keySet()`
- get the product with highest quantity from the map
- update the account's product reference if needed and store the account into the list

These advices translates to the following code:

```java
public static void handler2(List<Product_Test__c> newProds) {
    // This map holds the products with higher quantity for each account
    Map<Id, Product_Test__c> mapAccoutIdToProduct = new Map<Id, Product_Test__c>();
    for (Product_Test__c p : newProds) {
        // the first time you meet an Account "quantity" will be null
        Decimal quantity = mapAccoutIdToProduct.get(p.Account__c)?.Quantity__c;
        if (quantity == null || p.Quantity__c > quantity) {
            mapAccoutIdToProduct.put(p.Account__c, p);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acc : [SELECT Product_Test__c, Product_Test__r.Quantity__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :mapAccoutIdToProduct.keySet()]) {
        Product_Test__c prod = mapAccoutIdToProduct.get(acc.Id);
        // If the Account isn't linked to a product yet or if the new product's quantity is greater than the current one
        if (acc.Product_Test__c == null || prod.Quantity__c > acc.Product_Test__r.Quantity__c) {
            acc.Product_Test__c = prod.Id;
            accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
    }
    update accountsToUpdate;
}
```

Keep in mind that you should also take into account the update of `Product_Test__c`.
I.E. There are two products: P1 (quantity = 5) and P2 (quantity = 1).
Account A1 is linked to the P1.
P2's quantity is updated to 10, so A1 should now be linked to P2.

You can reuse the above code just changing

```java
if (acc.Product_Test__c == null || prod.Quantity__c > acc.Product_Test__r.Quantity__c)
```

to

```java
if (acc.Product_Test__c == null || (prod.Id != acc.Product_Test__c && prod.Quantity__c > acc.Product_Test__r.Quantity__c))
```